# "Хакерство" на java

Tags: java, взлом, cmd, eclipse

Учу java. Дошёл до внутренних классов. Написал такой код:

```
package a;

public class A 
{
    private int a;

    public A(int a) { this.a = a; }

    private class Internal
    {
        private void doSomething() { int b = A.this.a; }
    }
}
```

Таким образом компилятор добавляет в класс A метод:

```
static int access$0(a A);
```

(то, что имя метода именно такое, проверил с помощью рефлексии).

Допустим, я злоумышленник и хочу получить доступ к скрытому полю `а` класса `А`.
Добавляю я в папку `a`-файл Hacker.java, содержащий следующий код:

```
package a;

public class Hacker
{
    public static int getA(A a){
        return A.access$0(a);
    }
}
```

Компилирую его уже не через Eclipse, а через cmd вот так:

```
D:\6. ФПМИ\Информатика\JavaProjects>javac -classpath Internal\bin Internal\bin\a\Hacker.java
```

(т.е. пакет `a` у меня находится в `D:\6. ФПМИ\Информатика\JavaProjects\Internal\bin`), на что мне компилятор сообщает:

```
Internal\bin\a\Hacker.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                return A.access$0(a);
                        ^   symbol:   method access$0(A)   location: class A 1 error
```

Почему? Почему из меня такой плохой хакер?) В общем, объясните, пожалуйста, как надо. Но только доступно объясните, ибо я ещё просто студентик. )

Comment: Возможно, метод `access$0` приватный. Попробуйте вызвать его с помощью рефлексии.

Comment: Нет, он не приватный, а "пакетный", иначе компилятору не было бы смысла его создавать.
Я компилирую в два этапа. Сначала просто "приложение", а потом хочу внедрить новый класс "Hacker" в тот же пакет. Т.е. второй раз я компилирую только класс Hacker, указывая где искать нужные (уже скомпилированные) классы ("-classpath Internal\bin").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, компилятор Java достаточно умён, чтобы не позволить вам напрямую вызывать синтетические методы. А вот уже JVM можно обмануть. Для этого произведём следующие манипуляции:

- Скомпилируем класс `A` и в декомпиляторе посмотрим сигнатуру метода, сгенерированного для доступа к приватному полю. Пусть она будет `static int access$0(A a)`.
- Забэкапим скомпилированные классы `A.class` и `A$Internal.class`. В исходнике класса `A` удалим внутренний класс и добавим метод `access$0`:

> ```
> package a;
>
> public class A 
> {
>     private int a;
>
>     public A(int a) { this.a = a; }
>
>     static int access$0(A a) {
>         return a.a;
>     }
> }
> ```

- Скомпилируем эту версию класса `A`. Скомпилируем класс `Hacker`, указав в параметре `-classpath` компилятора путь к модифицированной версии класса `A`.
- Теперь можно заменить модифицированный класс `A` на оригинальный и запустить программу.

На уровне байт-кода не будет никакой принципиальной разницы между вызовами синтетического метода `access$0` и написанного нами метода с таким же именем. JVM не будет задумываться о корректности предоставления доступа к этому методу классу `Hacker`, она считает, что об этом позаботился компилятор (как видите, он не позволяет вам даже скомпилировать код, содержащий прямой вызов синтетического метода).

Теперь осталось придумать хоть одно практическое применение такого подхода. Ведь всё это можно было сделать без танцев с бубнами при помощи рефлексии.

Comment: Вот это да!!! То, что я хотел! Это реально круто) Спасибо! По-больше бы таких ответов! Только всё же не понятно, каким образом компилятор различает синтетический метод от обычного. Похоже, в *.class файлах синтетические методы каким-то образом помечаются, иначе как объяснить такое умное поведение компилятора... А на счёт рефлексии - такой инструмент уже знаю, просто хотелось как-то сыграть именно на недостатках встроенных классов (первый том Horstmann - на 297 стр. автор рассуждал об этом - меня заинтересовало). :)

Answer (score 0):

Я не "реал хакер онли", но даже я знаю, что этап компиляции и этап выполнения программы это разные вещи. Если во время выполнения или транслирования и добавляются какие-то свои методы, то во время компиляции о них точно ничего не известно. И если я не ошибаюсь (с java не знаком), то доступ к приватным полям и методам можно получить прямо из рефлексии: [Java Reflection - Private Fields and Methods](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/private-fields-and-methods.html).